# SPLUNK multi-value chart

Tags: rest, splunk, splunk-query

I have 2 values `restSevice` being which endpoint is called and `status` being the code returned from that endpoint. I would like todo a timechart so that x is time and y is the count of the status value combined with the restService called. ie if I called my `restService` `receiving` and/or `location` then there would be a line for each `status` returned so there would be a line for `receiving 200`, `receiving 404`, `location 200`, and `location 404`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the values of `restService` and `status` fields and assign it to a new field:

```
| your_search
| eval service_status = restService + " " + status
| timechart count by service_status
```